# Close Vscode Panel on killing the last Terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

Earlier The Panel of vscode used to close when I killed the terminal. But after I reset my pc and reinstall vscode, this is not happening. I after killing all the terminals I have to click on the "Close Panel" Button to close it.

How can I close the panel automatically on killing the last terminal?

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So the lower panel (or right/left panel if you moved it) should always automatically close if the terminal-view has had all of its terminals closed.

Now, with the above said, their is one exception, which is a common exception: When you show there panel with a view — *i.e. the problems view, output-logger, etc...* — with the terminal-view, the behavior of the panel changes. In the context I just described, the panel will not automatically close.

To solve the issue, remove all other views that share the panel with the terminal view. Then you should find that you get the expected behavior.

FYI, this has worked this way for a long time, and a while back (2+ years ago) there was a somewhat supported feature request to make the closing behavior of the panel more configurable — *e.g. like adding settings that close the panel when the terminal-view has no terminals open, even if it is in a shared panel* — however, I checked all settings & release notes and GitHub before answering this, and it appears that the panel & terminal view, in the context of this question, still behave the way that they always have since the first newer release of the non-beta VS Code.